# react native google map not show in android device

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

I want to integrate google map in my react-native application so below is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MapView  from 'react-native-maps';
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
return (
  <MapView
  style={styles.container}
  region={{
  latitude: 37.78825,
  longitude: -122.4324,
  latitudeDelta: 0.015,
  longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
  }}
     >
  /MapView>
   }
  );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
height: '100%',
width: '100%',
 }
});
```

when I run above code I get output as the blank page as below

[image]

any idea how can I solve this? your all suggestions are appreciable

Comment: Did you put Google maps API key in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @nhoxbypass : yes i put my api key in manifest file

Comment: I think so there is some issue with google key and permission. Can you please check key and google map settings to use key once?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you have missed including the google_services.json in your app's root folder. You will get this when you enable the Google Maps API from the Google Play Developer Console. And or are missing the correct API keys for the API.